# Issue with a dataset and OOP

Tags: python, database, oop

I am learning OOP with Python and I have a question about a code provided during the class. What it does is to find an apartment in a long dataset, according to some specifications. However, when I run the code, I am getting an error. What am I doing wrong here? Is it a problem with the path that I provided?

```
from modules.client import Client
from modules.re_agent import Agent
from modules.message import Message

# 1. Define client object and intial request
ms_smith = Client("Ms. Smith", ["60323", "60596"], 3, 2000, [])
parameters = ms_smith.raise_request()
text = """Dear James,
I am looking for a new apartment. Please find enclosed my
preferences for the maximum rent, rooms and location.
Best, Ms. Smith
"""
request_to_agent = Message(parameters, text)
# 2. Define agent object
james = Agent("James",
              "C:\\Users\\mateu\\Desktop\\PhD\\GSEFM 2021-22\\Programming\\Tutorials\\Tutorial 2\\programming_languages_2022_lecture_2_lc_4_i\\immoscout_flat_rents_202001_202006",
              [])

# 3. Transmit message to james
request_to_agent.to_recipient(james.inbox)

# 4. Let james search data
c_zip_codes = james.inbox[0][0]["zip_codes"]
c_rooms = james.inbox[0][0]["rooms"]
c_max_price = james.inbox[0][0]["max_price"]
ms_smith_data = james.build_client_dataset(c_zip_codes, c_rooms, c_max_price)

# 5. Compose message to Ms. Smith
try:
    assert type(ms_smith_data) != str
    text = """Good morning Ms. Smith,
    Thanks for your request. Please find enclosed some offers.
    Best,
    James
    """
except AssertionError:
    text = """Good morning Ms. Smith,
    Unfortunately, I could not find any apporpriate offers for you.
    Best,
    James
    """
response_to_smith = Message(ms_smith_data, text)

# 6. Send response to Ms. Smith
response_to_smith.to_recipient(ms_smith.inbox)

# 7. Print message in Ms. Smith's mailbox
print(ms_smith.inbox[0][1])
```

Error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-ab957ca9646b> in <module>
     24 c_rooms = james.inbox[0][0]["rooms"]
     25 c_max_price = james.inbox[0][0]["max_price"]
---> 26 ms_smith_data = james.build_client_dataset(c_zip_codes, c_rooms, c_max_price)
     27 
     28 # 5. Compose message to Ms. Smith

~\modules\re_agent.py in build_client_dataset(self, c_zip_codes, c_rooms, c_max_price)
     59         except AssertionError:
     60             return str("Empty!") # If zero, no obs were found before
---> 61         data = pd.concat(frames)
     62         # Deduplicate data in terms of object id
     63         data.drop_duplicates(subset= "object_id", keep = "first")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    272     ValueError: Indexes have overlapping values: ['a']
    273     """
--> 274     op = _Concatenator(
    275         objs,
    276         axis=axis,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy, sort)
    329 
    330         if len(objs) == 0:
--> 331             raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate")
    332 
    333         if keys is None:

ValueError: No objects to concatenate
```

Comment: The problem is within the (imported) module Agent. The function `build_client_dataset` is expecting some objects to concernate, but no objects are given. It is hard to say waht happens without the full program. That being said: if you are taking a class and this is some form of assignment, you are probably way better of with contacting your teacher who knows all about this code/assignment, than ask some random peaple on internet. Get some value for that money you pay! :)

Comment: Here in Germany we do not have to pay, but thanks for the clue @Damiaan.